# Rails Using Integers for Price

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Booking model with a price field. I have opted for an Integer data type to store the prices in pence and have a before_create call in my Booking model to convert the user inputted price in pounds to pence:

```
before_create { self.price = price * 100 } #convert to pence
```

However, I have noticed in my terminal that if I enter a decimal number on my form ( 22.75 for example ) it would be entered into my model as 2200 and not 2275.

I assume it's because the price field is an integer so it will have converted the 22.75 into 22 before it then applies the conversion to pence.

Should I tackle this in my controller do you think or is the model the right way to go?

**EDIT** I've decided to use DECIMAL instead of INTEGER to avoid the potential headache. There's loads of debate on this topic but most appear to recommend DECIMAL. Thanks for the advice everyone.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for converting the value outside of the model. If you convert from the model, soon or later, tricky things will happen. For example, you may provide pence value, and it will still be multiplied 100 times.

Always setting the value in correct unit would avoid any error for sure : if the price is in pence, always set it in pence. Conversion from pounds to pence is more something an helper or a lib should do.

Comment: I have to convert as I can't expect a user to do the conversion beforehand. Would you recommend catching the parameter in the Controller and getting a helper to then make the conversion before then passing to the model?

Comment: Indeed. That could be a method `#pounds_to_pence` in ApplicationContoller (and an `helper :pounds_to_pence` instruction to make it also available in views) to format it correctly, with probably the reverse `#pence_to_pounds` since you may want this in views for displaying prices. Or, since you may want to sanitize params values, that could be a dedicated PriceConvertor lib.

Comment: I assume I can get at the param with params[:booking][:price] - it's a multi-dimensional array right?

Comment: Well, it depends on how your form is built, but if you have something like `form_for( @booking) do |f|; [...]; f.text_field :price`, it's in `params[:booking][:price]`, yes (as string value).

Comment: It appears to be typecasted before it hits the controller

Comment: Do you inspect `params` hash itself, before assigning its values to model ? I've just tested against a form with a integer value for a field, and typecast is only done when assigning values to model.

Answer (score 0):

Give adding some helper methods a try.

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  def price_dollars
    self.price / 100
  end

  def price_dollars=(val)
    self.price = val * 100
  end
end
```

This should help so that when it's SET it will * 100 and when showing just use booking1.price_dollars for decimal display.

Comment: I deliberately set Integer for the price datatype and is actually quite a common way of doing it.

Comment: Editing answer having seen that.

Answer (score 0):

**Better not talking about filter. The issue is not there.**

I made an experiment on your question.

In one of my demo apps I have a model Task. Then I added a price field in integer type, and copied your before_create filter.

The result? It get same result without touching the filter yet.

```
task = Task.new(title: 'foo', price: 22.75)
task.title
#=> 'foo'
task.price
#=> 22
task.price.to_f
#=> 22.0
```

See, the value has been converted to integer at initialization of the object. The filter has even taken effect yet.

So, for your case, I think the best solution is to make it consistent, saving all price as pence, and convert it when needed.

#### Another consideration in model

Of course for current fix, processing data in controller is doable.

Another possible approach is to write another method based on #new

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ....
  # Remove that callback

  def new_with_price_format(*args)
    if args[:price].is_a?(Float)
       args[:price] *= 100
    end
    new(*args)
  end
```

Then in controller

```
  @booking = Booking.new_with_price_format(params[:booking])
```

Comment: Yeah you're right - I just did a test too and when it arrives at the controller it's already an integer